# How to switch on the mobile devices programatically in android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am working on alarm clock and I want to check whether phone is switched on or off when alarm ringing on set time.

If phone is switched off then switch it on and ring the alarm.

Comment: have you tried something....

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852882/how-to-detect-android-phone-is-being-turned-off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this it may help you**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN
`

```
<receiver android:name=".ShutdownReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>`
```